# Converting multiple JSON arrays

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have been kindly provided with the code below to convert a JSON array to a single object. I would like to use the same code to change multiple properties. All arrays will have a single object.

I would like to add some code that will walk through the JSON and execute the code below on any properties that have been found. Most properties are nested, hence the need to walk through the JSON.

```
// Load the JSON from a file into a JObject
JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"output.json"));

// Get the desired property whose value is to be replaced
var prop = o1.Property("to_Description");

// Replace the property value with the first child JObject of the existing value
prop.Value = prop.Value.Children<JObject>().FirstOrDefault();

// write the changed JSON back to the original file
File.WriteAllText(@"output.json", o1.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the middle two lines with these:

```
// Find all properties anywhere in the JSON whose values are arrays
var arrayProperties = o1.Descendants()
                        .OfType<JProperty>()
                        .Where(p => p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array);

foreach (JProperty prop in arrayProperties)
{
    // Replace the property value with the first child JObject of the existing value
    prop.Value = prop.Value.Children<JObject>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iP8Ibd